# i have an error while export excel file using c# mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i am using asp.net mvc webapi and ajax in my project

i am calling controller using ajax and sending data with ajax

here is my ajax code

```
var bobj = {};
bobj.data = data;
CallAjax('post',common,'attendancesheetdownload',bobj,_getholidaylist.onsuccestendancesheetdownload, '');

    function CallAjax(method, baseUrl, strUrl, strData, onSuccess, onFailure) {
        callDebugger();
        var dataValue = null;
        var ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        strUrl = baseUrl + strUrl;
        method = method.toUpperCase();
        if (method == "GET") {
            dataValue = strData;
        }
        else if (method == "POST") {
            dataValue = JSON.stringify(strData);
        }
        callLoader(true);
        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: strUrl,//users/signin
            contentType: ContentType,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: dataValue,
            async: false,
            success: onSuccess,
            error: function (err) {
                callLoader(false);
                swal({
                    title:err, text: "", type: "error",
                    showCancelButton: false, closeOnConfirm: true, confirmButtonText: "OK",
                }, function (isConfirm) {
                    window.location = "signin";
                });
                 //console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

and here is my c# controller code for excel generate

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("attendancesheetdownload")]
public JsonResult AttendanceSheetDownload(List<AttendanceModel> data)
{
    //List<AttendanceModel> holidaylist = new List<AttendanceModel>();
    try
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {


            //DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Employee Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Leaves");
  //          dt.Columns.Add("URL");
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                var row = dt.NewRow();

                row["Employee Name"] = item.user_id;
                row["Leaves"] = Convert.ToString(item.days);
              //  row["URL"] = item.URL;

                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
           // dt = attendacemodel;
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "CusDetail");
            wb.ShowRowColHeaders = false;
            wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
            wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Customers.xlsx");
            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();

            }
        }
        return Json(data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        data = null;
    }
}
```

i dont see any error at c# side it easly pass all the step but the file is not downloading 
and 
when its comes to onsuccess method of ajax its give me `object object` error

can some one guide me how to download excel file with ajax c# and webapi

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: If you want to download a file on client side then why do you return JSON? See [Returning binary file from controller in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: what i have to return instad of json

Comment: Content with proper ContentType.

Comment: can u please explain with example i am new in this

Comment: Try to use google or I'll find it to you 'https://stackoverflow.com/a/40242528/4275342

Comment: what should i return in datatype in ajax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168411/discussion-between-chitra-nandpal-and-roman-marusyk).